# Normal vector to plane

Tags: vectors

Suppose we have the plane with equation  $3x-7z=12$. How to find its normal vector?

The plane with equation $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ has the normal vector $\mathbb{n}=(A,B,C)$.
Using this we get that above plane has normal vector $(3,0,-7)$, right?

Let's apply another method. Take three points which lies on the plane, namely $A=(4,0,0), \ B=(0,0,-\frac{12}{7}), \ C=(1,0,\frac{-9}{7})$ then vector $AB=(-4,0,-\frac{12}{7})$ and $AC=(-3,0,-\frac{9}{7})$. Taking their cross product we get zero vector. 
What is wrong in my idea?

Comment: You have an error: $AC=(-3,0,9/7)$.

Comment: The third component of point $C$ shoul have sign minus, namely $-9/7$

Comment: I don't think that's true.

Comment: Why? Maybe I am tired of. Could you show it?

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 8):

**In response to the first part:**

Suppose two points, $P(x,y,z)$ and $P_0(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ lie on a plane with a normal vector $\mathbf{n}$. Also, let $\mathbf{r}$ denote the position vector of $P$ and $\mathbf{r_0}$ denote the position vector of $P_0$.

[image]

The picture clearly shows that $\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{r-r_0}) = 0$, since the two vectors are perpendicular. Then, $$\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{r_0}$$ In your case, we have $3x+0y-7z = 12$, which is equivalent to $(3,0,-7)\cdot(x,y,z) = 12$. Comparing with above, we have the components of the normal to the plane are $(3,0,-7)$.

**Second question:**

You have made a computation mistake, as has been pointed out in the other posts. Your idea is nonetheless true: if you have two direction vectors lying in the plane, then their cross product will result in a vector orthogonal to both these vectors, i.e. normal to the plane.

Comment: Your answer to the second (and actual) question is wrong. OP has no arithmetic mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:** the answer that was here (written 6 years ago) was quite wrong as pointed out by Tetix in the comments. For posterity's sake I will try to write a correct one this time.

The points $A = (4,0,0)$, $B = (0,0,-12/7)$, and $C = (1,0,-9/7)$ all lie on the plane $P$ with equation $3x-7z = 12$. One computes $AB = (-4,0,-12/7)$ and $AC = (-3,0,-9/7)$. As pointed out by michaelvanleeuwen, this is sort of unlucky. $AB$ is a scalar multiple of $AC$; $AB = \frac{4}{3}AC$. In particular, $AB\times AC$ is zero.

When computing the normal vector to a plane with this method of choosing a pair of vectors parallel to the plane, it is necessary that the vectors not be linearly independent. So, let's try it again. Take $A = (4,0,0)$, $B = (0,0,-12/7)$, and $C = (1,1,-9/7)$. $AB = (-4,0,-12/7)$ as before and $AC = (-3,1,-9/7)$. After a little bit of algebra, one finds
$$\boxed{AB\times AC = (12/7,0,-4)}$$
The original normal vector that was pointed out is $(3,0,-7)$, and one has
$$(AB\times AC) = (4/7)\cdot (3,0,-7)$$
showing the calculation returns an equivalent result (up to scaling).

Comment: We have an equation $3x-7z=12$ I don't think that point $C=(1,0,9/7)$ lie on plane because if we put them into plane's equation we don't get identity. Since $3*1-7*\frac{9}{7}=-6\neq 12$

Comment: @ZFR agree. That's what I was thinking.

Comment: Your answer is totally wrong. You have mistakes in calculations. Your $C$ does NOT belong on the plane. $\frac{-9}{7}$ is indeed correct and the cross product is indeed 0 vector. The reason this happens is explained better in above answer from @michaelfvanleeuwen which is the only correct one that actually gives insight and actually answers OP question.

Comment: You're correct, of course. It should be mentioned that the numbers in the problem were changed (though the original numbers $(1,0,9/7)$ indeed did not lie on the plane.) I probably mistakenly took that on faith at the time. I'll edit this later. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your two chosen vectors are parallel - all three points are on a line in the plane - so their cross-product will necessarily be zero; if you choose one of your three points to not lie in the same line in the plane then the cross-product will be parallel to your extracted normal vector.

Comment: This is the only correct answer in this question. OP decided to choose $y=0$ for all considered points $A, B, C$ which has as a result all 3 points to lie on a LINE on the plane. You could choose a point like $(4, 5000000, 0)$, it also lies in the plane. This fact results in a cross product of 0, which is totally correct. If OP choose non-collinear points $A, B, C$ he can find the correct normal through the cross product.

Answer (score -1):

the vector $$\vec{AC}$$ is given by $$\vec{AC}=\left(-3;0;\frac{9}{7}\right)$$
$$A(4;0;0),C\left(1;0;\frac{9}{7}\right)$$ then $$\vec{AC}=\left(1-4;0-0;\frac{9}{7}-0\right)$$

Comment: Your point $C$ does not lie on plane $3x-7z=12$ since $3*1-7*\frac{9}{7}=-6\neq 12$