# Find an equation for a plane parallel to a plane so that a point is equidistant to both planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

I am having trouble with this problem in my Linear Algebra review:

> Find an equation for the plane parallel to $2x-y+2z=4 $ such that the
> point $(3,2,-1) $ is equidistant from both planes.

The answer is $2x-y+2=0$ . How would you go about finding the $0$ ?

Comment: The last term on the left side of the answer should be $2z$, not $2.$

Comment: take any point on the original plane, say $(0;0;2)$, construct vector from it to the point $(3;2;-1)$, you'll get $(3;2;-3)$, add this vector to $(3;2;-1)$ to get a point from the plane you are looking for, namely $(6;4;-4)$. Now you know that your eq. should be $2x-y+2z=d$ and you have one point, thus you can solve for $d$, i.e. $2\times 6 - 4 + 2 \times (-4) = 0 = d$.

Comment: Find the equation of the plan parallel to  - the plane through the point and move it the same difference of the "free" value to get the desired plane.

Answer (score 1):

Since both planes are parallel, the [normal vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472153/normal-vector-to-plane) to both planes is $(2, -1, 2)$. Thus the points $(2k + 3, -k + 2, 2k-1)$ and $(-2k + 3, k + 2, -2k-1)$ are equidistant to $(3,2,-1)$.

Now if the first point lies on the original plane, $2(2k + 3) - (-k + 2) + 2(-2k + 1) = 4$ $ \implies k = -2$. So the original plane is moved $-2$ units to meet the point $(3,2,-1)$, then another $-2$ units for it to be equidistant gives $2x - y + 2z = 4 + (-2) + (-2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the point $(3,2,−1)$ to be equidistant from two distinct parallel planes, it must be midway between them. Furthermore, one plane is a reflection of the other plane through the point $(3,2,−1).$

The point $P_2 = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is in the second (unknown) plane if and only if there is a corresponding point $P_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ in the plane $2x−y+2z=4$ such that the point $(3,2,−1)$ is the midpoint of the line segment $\overline{P_1P_2}.$
That is,

\begin{align}
\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} &= 3, \\[3pt]
\frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} &= 2, \\[3pt]
\frac{z_1 + z_2}{2} &= -1.
\end{align}

Solve these equations for the coordinates of $P_1$:

\begin{align}
x_1 &= 6 - x_2, \\
y_1 &= 4 - y_2, \\
z_1 &= -2 - z_2.
\end{align}

We know that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ lies in the given plane, so
$$2x_1 − y_1 + 2z_1 = 4.$$

Use the equations above to substitute for $x_1,$ $y_1,$ and $z_1$:

$$ 2(6 - x_2) − (4 - y_2) + 2(-2 - z_2) = 4. $$

That's an equation of a plane, and it is the desired plane.
But to put it in the form that is probably expected, we can simplify:

\begin{align}
 12 - 2x_2 − 4 + y_2 - 4 - 2z_2 &= 4, \\
- 2x_2  + y_2 - 2z_2 &= 0,  && \text{collect all the constant terms}\\
2x_2  - y_2  + 2z_2 &= 0.  && \text{multiply all terms by $-1$}\\
\end{align}

Done!